# Is there an equivalent way to do MySQL's JSONOBJECTAGG() in MariaDB?

Tags: mysql, json, database, mariadb

The server I was working on for a data project crashed and I am now recreating the database. I used to be working on a MySQL database, and now I'm using MariaDB. I have never used MariaDB before.

Previously, I used the following command to insert some data into one table from another:

```
CREATE TABLE collaborators_list 
SELECT awards.id, awards.researcher_name, awards.organization_id, 
    JSON_OBJECTAGG(awards.fiscal_year, coapplicants.coapplicant_name, 
    coapplicants.organization_number) 
AS 'coapplicants_list' FROM awards 
INNER JOIN coapplicants 
ON awards.id=coapplicants.id 
GROUP BY awards.researcher_name, awards.organization_id;
```

Basically, I want to do the same thing in MariaDB. I tried looking here:
https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/json-functions/
but unless I am misreading something, none of these is what I really want...

Help!

Comment: No, but even `JSON_OBJECTAGG` takes only two columns/expressions as argument. So your usage seems wrong. Ref: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_json-objectagg

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**No**, MariaDB still does not support `JSON_ARRAYAGG` and `JSON_OBJECTAGG` functions. A JIRA ticket has been raised for requesting this feature: https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-16620

Now, from the docs of [`JSON_OBJECTAGG()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_json-objectagg):

> It takes **only** two column names or expressions as arguments, the
>   first of these being used as a key and the second as a value.
>
> An error occurs if any key name is NULL or the number of arguments is
>   not equal to 2.

However, you are specifying three arguments in `JSON_OBJECTAGG(awards.fiscal_year, coapplicants.coapplicant_name, coapplicants.organization_number)`; **so your attempted query will not work as well**.

Now, in the absence of the required functions, we can utilize [`Group_Concat()`](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/group_concat/) with [`Concat()`](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/concat/). I am assuming that you need only first two arguments (as explained in previous para).

```
GROUP_CONCAT( DISTINCT CONCAT('"', awards.fiscal_year, '": "',
                              coapplicants.coapplicant_name, '"') 
              SEPARATOR ', ')
```

**Note** that, in case of string getting very very long, Group_Concat() *may* truncate it. So, you can increase the allowed length, by executing the following query, before the above query:

```
SET SESSION group_concat_max_len = @@max_allowed_packet;
```

Comment: @ellen: Here a version, see [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=6c202c2f467e6a7f2b879d9db464a095).

Comment: @Madhur Thanks for your response! I will be giving this a try in the next couple days so will get back to you. This looks like it will help for sure

Comment: Doesn't `GROUP_CONCAT` cut off the resulting string after a predetermined number of bytes (usually a setting in the database)?

Comment: @TimoHuovinen Before executing this query, you can use `SET SESSION group_concat_max_len = @@max_allowed_packet;`

Comment: i once a [comment sparring session](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58009450/2548147) with @RickJames  in the past  why `SET SESSION group_concat_max_len = @@max_allowed_packet;` might be bad to use..  it still remains a bit off a question mark what happens under the hood memory and performance wise with the mentioned `sort_buffer_size` setting in combination with a possible implicit `ORDER BY` in  `GROUP_CONCAT()` in some the more modern MySQL or MariaDB (for that matter) versions,  i still didn't took a look into it..

Comment: JSON_ARRAYAGG is enable from 10.5.0 version :) 
https://mariadb.com/kb/en/json_arrayagg/