# Get groups of object ids with datetime grouped by date

Tags: mysql, mariadb

Let's say we have table like this:

```
+----------------------------------+----------------------------+
| id                               | start                      |
+----------------------------------+----------------------------+
| 06c561305383482e98064ssdfd6ccf74 | 2019-08-30 14:41:40.697301 |
| 0aec07d9acdd48c485ab3sfhsffdsa8c | 2019-09-02 05:45:09.274541 |
| 0d240asdfasd49579e2be8821b908fdc | 2019-09-02 05:45:08.745885 |
| 00al4eebb9a34sdsdfsdff128518dc4f | 2019-08-30 14:42:29.094314 |
```

Is it possible to get data in structure similar to this in single query?
I want to get data grouped by unique dates with all object ids in date group.

```
date:
    2019-08-30:
       ids: 
           - 06c561305383482e98064ssdfd6ccf74 
           - 00al4eebb9a34sdsdfsdff128518dc4f
    2019-09-02:
       ids: 
           - 0aec07d9acdd48c485ab3sfhsffdsa8c
           - 0d240asdfasd49579e2be8821b908fdc
```

Comment: ```GROUP_CONCAT(id) ... GROUP BY date(`start`)```?

Comment: Is there a other programming language (like PHP) involved as your expected result looks like a display format or a "pseudo JSON" format which you would want to send to the application?

Comment: Also if you follow @SalmanA 's suggestion which is most likely correct don't forgot to run `SET SESSION group_concat_max_len = @@max_allowed_packet;` otherwise you are going to hit the 1024 char lenght max where `GROUP_CONCAT` silently truncates without errors

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Salaman

```
SELECT DATE(tab.start), GROUP_CONCAT(id) FROM tab GROUP BY DATE(tab.start);
```

Works like a charm!

Remember also about setting:

```
SET SESSION group_concat_max_len = @@max_allowed_packet;
```

Comment: it can still fail `GROUP_CONCAT` max char lenght  is 1024 you need to run `SET SESSION group_concat_max_len = @@max_allowed_packet;` before that query..

Comment: @RaymondNijland - That may be risky, especially if you have `max_allowed_packet` set to a large value.

Comment: *"That may be risky, .. have max_allowed_packet set to a large value."* @RickJames Why? As the manual saids about max_allowed_packet "It is safe to increase the value of this variable because the extra memory is allocated only when needed." meaning group_concat_max_len automatic safely scales with it atleast that is what i am assuming based on manual information... I am not really seeing the point about your warning here maybe when you have extremely big groups (in the millions) to be string concated maybe then it can become a issue then anyhow would you be using `GROUP_CONCAT(..)` then? ..

Comment: @RaymondNijland - I hope you are right.  But I am skeptical.  I have never heard of any case where MySQL will avoid allocating memory that would lead to _swapping_.  Also, I wonder how it allocates the group_concat space -- 1KB, then 2KB, then 4KB, etc, until it has enough, or hits the limit?  I would hope it does that rather than blindly allocating the max.  I think `net_buffer_length` grows up to `max_allowed_packet`.  And it seems like something else used to always be allocated at the max, but later "grew as needed".

Comment: @RaymondNijland - Found it...  As of 5.6.4, `sort_buffer_size` grows as needed, rather than being malloced to the given setting.

Comment: @RickJames, i understood why you was skeptical about it as i also found some wierd things in the source code in the past.. But still  i doubt about that `sort_buffer_size ` setting as implicit/explicit sorting is deprecated with `GROUP BY` in the modern MySQL versions in MySQL 8 it is even removed so MySQL 8 never touches `sort_buffer_size` in this query case.. Unless offcource `GROUP_CONCAT` also has a implicit `ORDER BY` anyhow not sure i never fully researched in the source code how `GROUP_CONCAT` internally works